# REGEX for lists

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

Is it possible to use PHP's `preg_match` for variable length patterns? For example, a JSON style list.

The following REGEX

```
\{[0-9]*\:[0-9]*\}
```

Matches for

```
{1:2,2:7}
```

However I also need it to match for

```
{1:9,2:8}
```

I envisioned something like

```
\{([0-9]*\:[0-9]*)[\,[0-9]*\:[0-9]*]*\}
```

With some sort of non required, yet valid, grouping with a `*`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/ZPSvs2/2

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Should your first example be `{1:2}`?

Comment: If possible try to avoid REGEX, it can make your code unreadable. Regular expression can sometimes be useful, but often there is a better solution. In your example I would use `json_decode()` and work from there.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That was my thought as well, but I don't believe `json_decode()` would handle the *keys* being numeric.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware as the data I'm using isn't true JSON (which is why I've run in to this problem) I'm looking for a temporary workaround to validate it until the data is migrated to JSON format - I agree with your advice though, I'd have wanted to use `json_decode` and `json_last_error` to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\{[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+:[0-9]+)?}
```

or - if you also want to match strings like `{2:5,445:46,54567:5677}` - use

```
\{[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+:[0-9]+)*}
                                 ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3SD1a/1)

**Details**:

- `\{` - a `{` symbol (it is not necessary to escape it, but still a good idea)
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `:`  - a colon (no need to escape it as it is not a special regex metacharacter)
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,[0-9]+:[0-9]+)?`  - 1 or 0 (due to `?`, replace with `*` if you need to allow 0 or more) sequences of:

  - `,`  - a comma
  - `[0-9]+:[0-9]+` - see above
- `}` - ending literal `}`.

A shorter version of the same regex that uses a subroutine:

```
\{([0-9]+:[0-9]+)(?:,(?1))?}
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3SD1a/2) where `(?1)` repeats the Group 1 pattern.

Comment: Perfect thank you for the breakdown of the details, this makes sense and works for the situation.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be after is:

```
{\d+:\d+(,\d+:\d+)*}
```

which will match:

- A leading and trailing curly bracket
- One or more digits, a colon, and one or more digits.
- Zero or more times:

  - A comma followed by one or more digits, a colon, and one or more digits.

This handles additional cases, such as `{1:9,2:8,2:7}`